# Changes to entity not registering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update a list in one of my entities. This is what I'm doing:

```
var loggedInUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

var x = Request["groupCode"];
var affectedGroup = db.StudentGroups.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Code == x);
var groupId = affectedGroup.Id;
if (affectedGroup != null)
{
    if (affectedGroup.StudentIds == null)
    {
        affectedGroup.StudentIds = new List<string>();
    }
    if (affectedGroup.StudentIds.Contains(loggedInUserId))
    {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You are already a member of this group";
    }
    else
    {
        affectedGroup.StudentIds.Add(loggedInUserId);
        db.SaveChanges();   
    }
}
```

Here is my StudentGroup model:

```
public class StudentGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The group must have a name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The code is required.")]
    public string Code { get;set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Members")]
    public IList<string> StudentIds { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that StudentIds is always null when I run it in the debugger, even though when I step through it, the Id does get added.
I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, so please bear that in mind.

Comment: you should dispose of your context using a `using` block

Comment: The group code exists, it is taken from a form via POST. I made sure it matches my test data.

Comment: It is actually a many-to-many relationship, and I previously had some problems when storing the actual users. I think it has to do with the models being in different contexts (student is based on IdentityUser in the default context, which was already set up when I made the project, while StudentGroup is in a context I made), but I don't remember the exact details of the problem. As I said, I'm new to this and just trying to make it work, then I can make it work right.

Comment: I see. I think you need to redesign your relationships . You are right about the IdentityUser, it's a little bit confusing at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a Cross reference table to handle this functionality instead. You could have your StudentGroup model have an Id, Code, Name, and Description fields; Then create a xStudentsInStudentGroup table that stores a StudentId and StudentGroupId to relate the two.

The rest of your code would be semi similar. You can still get the groupId the same way, but once you have it you can pull all of the student Ids from the xStudentsInStudentGroup and use them however.

```
if(context.xStudentsInStudentGroup.Any(x => groupId == x.StudentGroupId &&  x.StudentId == loggedInUserId))
{
   //Already in
}
else
{
  var xStudent = new xStudentsInStudenGroup()
  {
    StudentId = loggedInUserId
    StudentGroupId = GroupId
  };
  context.Insert(xStudent);//This depends on how you add new records
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would also look into how you are setting up your controllers. You should have a base that creates and disposes a new database context every action. Or do a using statement that will clean the context up as stated before.

--EDIT--
The reason I don't recommend the way you are doing is because it doesn't seem to make sense that you could save a list of ints and have it update. If you have this working in other areas then maybe your issue is just that you have the StudentIds object as a list of string and not ints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code and make it work like this:

```
var x = Request["groupCode"];
var affectedGroup = db.StudentGroups.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Code == x);
var groupId = affectedGroup.Id;

if (affectedGroup != null && !affectedGroup.Any())
   {
      affectedGroup.StudentIds = new List<string>();
      affectedGroup.StudentIds.Add(loggedInUserId);   
   }
else if (affectedGroup.StudentIds.Contains(loggedInUserId))
   {
      TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You are already a member of this group";
   }

db.SaveChanges();
```

Also, you might want to use EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Add to make sure EF is aware of the changes.

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. When the code runs again, studentIds is null, even though I call SaveChanges.

Comment: Does loggedInUserId has a value when debugging? Also, check the updated answer to see if looking at EntityState helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not use EF lazy loading, thus when trying to receive the group you have to explicitly include the student ids using the Include method:

```
db.StudentGroups.Include(s => s.StudentIds).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Code == x);
```